# Runtime Controling Tensorflow module

Tags: python, tensorflow, control-flow

I have a neural network module implemented with TensorFlow and i want to  control it in run-time.

It seems that basic python object-oriented features, cant help me with this problem.

I want to run the DNN and receive precision and ... of that network in run-time and according to that information, i would like to control some parameters of that running DNN (changing parameters in each epoch).
it can be two separate modules... one is DNN and other is control module.

Can i use DNN in CLASS form and track its changes?

Is this problem relevant to socket programing?
(Sorry for bad English :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Keras Callbacks](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/keras/custom_callback) let you call custom methods at the start or the end of each epoch or batch. You can use them to do tasks like visualization, early stopping, or changing the learning rate at runtime.